# In macOS Catalina, how to load kext?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

When I disabled SIP via recovery mode, the kext could be loaded by kextload, anyway, when system restart, kext will not be loaded by kext manager like it supposed to be in Mojave and lower.

If I enabled SIP and load the kext (the kext is full functional with 10.14 -), it will show following message

```html
Kext rejected due to system policy: <OSKext 0x7ff02df0b450 [0x7fff89d4aba0]> { URL = "file:///Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions/...
```

BTW, In Catalina, how user to allow a kext ? I know in 10.13, it will show on the General of Security & Privacy, in 10.14, I was using Kextdrop, anyway, kextdrop won't work with Catalina.

Comment: I enabled SIP and use command 'spctl kext-consent disable' to disable the consent, the kext could be loaded by command line like kextload and kextutil -b, but the kext manager won't load it automatically when system start up as Mojave and High Sierra did

Comment: If both SIP and kext-consent enabled, the kext needs get notarized

Answer (score 1):

Found out I just need sign the kext and notarize the kext in order to get system to load it